# nodejs shutdown hook on killall

Tags: node.js, hook, shutdown

I'm trying to bind some shutdown function to my nodejs application (version 0.8.12). Since I'm spawning A LOT of child processes and working in a distributed evironment, I'm currently killing the application through

```
var n = spawn('killall', ['node']);
```

The problem is that with this apparently the `on('exit', ...)` logic is no longer working, indeed I have something like this:

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    if(exit_cb)
        exit_cb()
    else
        console.log('About to exit.');
});
```

And it's not firing whenever I kill the application.

Is there a way to add a shutdown hook with a `killall` command or should I find another way to kill my child processes in order to have the hook working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to listen for `SIGTERM` signal that `killall` sends by dafault. But also you need to stop your process manually after all jobs was finished.

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    if(exit_cb) {
        exit_cb();
        process.exit();
    } else {
        console.log('About to exit.');
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Apparently, this is not working in Node 0.8.14, I would be glad if anybody could confirm this.
This is marked as correct since it works in the version I was using at the time of the question (0.8.12).

Comment: Works fine for me in node v0.8.14.